# Swing and JPanels, layout managers

Tags: java, swing, alignment, jpanel, layout-manager

I've tried working with swing (for the first time) a few weeks ago and I ventured on my own for a bit to get a better feel for it. I seem to be running into a problem with vertical alignment.

Here is the situation: i have a boxlayout(Y_AXiS) JPanel in the West part of a borderlayout. Inside the JPanel w/ boxlayout, I have two other JPanels which I want to be vertically aligned (pushed towards the top of the screen no matter the dimensions of the frame). However, the layout manager seems to put a big vertical space between the two JPanels. I was thinking maybe a gridlayout would be better suited for this, but am unsure. I've tried numerous times to google for an answer and to correct the problem with no luck. Help Please!

```
package com.granet;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import java.awt.*;


public class CustomerOrganizer  extends JFrame
{
    public CustomerOrganizer()
    {
        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
        topPanel.setBackground(Color.darkGray);

        JLabel customerSlogan = new JLabel("Customer Organizer");

        topPanel.add(customerSlogan);



        JPanel leftPanel = new JPanel();
        leftPanel.setBackground(Color.darkGray);
        leftPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10,100,00,0));


        leftPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(leftPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        DrawPanel firstTab = new DrawPanel(Color.white, 350, 50);
        DrawPanel secondTab = new DrawPanel(Color.white, 350, 50);

        JLabel firstTabText = new JLabel("First Tab");
        JLabel secondTabText = new JLabel("Second Tab");

        firstTab.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0,60,60,0));
        secondTab.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0,60,60,0));

        firstTab.add(firstTabText);
        secondTab.add(secondTabText);


        leftPanel.add(firstTab);
        leftPanel.add(secondTab);

        firstTab.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
        secondTab.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);

/*      DOESN'T WORK, I'm pretty sure this changes the point on the jpanel which used for alignment (top, bottom, left or right) 
        firstTab.setAlignmentY(Component.TOP_ALIGNMENT);
        secondTab.setAlignmentY(Component.TOP_ALIGNMENT);
*/      


        add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(leftPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);

        pack();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        CustomerOrganizer frame = new CustomerOrganizer();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(700,400);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

DrawPanel.java

```
package com.granet;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class DrawPanel extends JPanel
{
    Color color;
    int width;
    int height;

    public DrawPanel(Color color, int width, int height)
    {
        this.color=color;
        this.width=width;
        this.height=height;
    }

    public DrawPanel()
    {
        this.color = Color.darkGray;
        this.width=this.getWidth();
        this.height=this.getHeight();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        g.setColor(color);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
    }
}
```

and this is what I see when I run it:
http://concertforhope.net/citeforme/javabug.png

Notice that the bottom tab is not pushed up against the top tab.

NVM, I see why. The tabs weren't that small, I was filling in the background the wrong way (the white boxes didn't represent the actual tabs). Thanks for the help.

Comment: Sorry about that @Snicolas , uploaded the other class and a screenshot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a bug. A boxlayout is supposed to divide the entire space equally between the components.

You'd probably want a flowlayout vertically or something like that.

I'd really suggest you get [Google WindowBuilder](http://code.google.com/javadevtools/download-wbpro.html) (free) and play a bit with layouts in the GUI.

In your special case you could also consider [JTabbedPane](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTabbedPane.html#JTabbedPane%28int%29) with a tab placement on the right.

Answer (score 4):

You might also consider [*Using Invisible Components as Filler*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html#filler) to control the vertical spacing. For example, [`org.gcs.kinetic.ControlPanel`](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/kineticmodel/code#ControlPanel) uses `Box.createVerticalStrut()`, while this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6072956/how-to-correct-center-gridlayout-using-standard-java-layout-managers/6076340#6076340) uses `Box.createVerticalGlue()`.