# setVisible(true) changes all instances visible

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have a class that extends JPanel and when I try to set one specific instance of the class to visible, all other classes expand aswell. Ideas?

Before 'two' CENTER is set visible:
[image: Before 'two' opens]

After 'two' CENTER is set visible:
[image]

notice that all other instances open. Here is the best I can do with my code since it is very abstract:

Call -

```
display.mainScrollPane.getMainPanel().getMachineListPanel().getMachine("two").panel.showPanel();
```

Comment: How did you create these objects? Most likely what's happening is that you have several references all pointing to the same object.

Comment: Are you using a static variable?

Comment: I'm always getting a thrills when I see invocations like this `display.mainScrollPane.getMainPanel().getMachineListPanel().getMachine("two").panel.showPanel();` and I must inspect that code. Try to redesign your approach.

Comment: Post a SSCCE  for proper help

Comment: A `GridLayout` would produce that effect.  Use a `BoxLayout` instead.  (And if that does not solve the problem, post an SSCCE.)

Answer (score 0):

Absent your [sscce](http://sscce.org/) it's hard to say.

- If you are using `BorderLayout`, note that components in the `CENTER` will expand to fill the available space. Alternatively, consider `BoxLayout`, illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3175280/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6076340/230513).
- If you are adding components *after* `pack()` and `setVisible()`, be sure to `validate()` and `repaint()` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5751044/230513).

Answer (score 0):

The cause was due to the fact that the MachineListPanel implements GridLayout. By definition, GridLayout forces all elements to be the same height and width -- ie. when one of the components' CENTER was set visible, the space also had to be allocated for all other elements in the layout.